# Deploying ADF application in Glassfish 4

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have deployed an ADF application in Glassfish. But when the application is loaded in the browser and the navigation is clicked the page just get refreshed and the intended page content is not getting loaded. When I checked the server error log the below error.

```
[2016-11-26T15:17:18.839+0530] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1480153638839] [levelValue: 1000] [[

java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._skipBoundary(MultipartFormHandler.java:247)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:75)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._startConfiguratorServiceRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

I searched google and got some suggested solutions like [this](http://myfaces.10567.n7.nabble.com/Trinidad-File-upload-issue-td30231.html)

But I am unable to locate the file specified in it and I am not sure how to do it.

I also tried replacing the trinidad-impl.jar as mentioned in [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3878927) but getting server error when running.

I am using Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0 and Glassfish 4.1

Please help me fix this issue so that I can make my adf application live.

Comment: Looks like a bug in GF. The second link has a downloadable version of GF here,http://www.spazioit.com/software/glassfish.zip, did you try that? Otherwise I suggest checking my oracle support and see if there is a workaround there until oracle patches the bug.

Comment: Yes. I downloaded and tried that version of glassfish (5.0) and the issue persists.