# Deploying ADF application1.2.2.1.4.0 in Glassfish 4.1

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, glassfish-4.1

I have Deployed oracle jdeveloper 1.2.2.1.4.0 in glassfish server 4.1,But when i inter username and password for login page ,just get refreshed ,but in log file i see the login is correct and i see the print message after login .my problem is i can't move between pages.

same problem but no answer: [Deploying ADF application in Glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817534/deploying-adf-application-in-glassfish-4)

this is from logs:

```
[2021-11-23T07:53:56.616+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646836616] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Resource META-INF/adf-config.xml not found on the classpath.]]

[2021-11-23T07:53:56.616+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646836616] [levelValue: 900] [[
  A default implementation of ADFConfig is being created for application. This can lead to unexpected results in some cases. Please add a basic META-INF/adf-config.xml to your classpath to avoid functional errors.]]

[2021-11-23T07:53:56.616+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.applicationScope] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646836616] [levelValue: 800] [[
  adding applicationScope with key oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl@284b32fc]]

[2021-11-23T07:53:56.820+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1637646836820] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ADFc: Limiting the number of RootViewPorts to 20]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:06.044+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646846044] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF_FACES-60142:ParserConfigurationException was thrown. The feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' is probably not supported by your XML processor.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:06.044+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646846044] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF_FACES-60142:ParserConfigurationException was thrown. The feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl' is probably not supported by your XML processor.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:06.044+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646846044] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF_FACES-60142:ParserConfigurationException was thrown. The feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities' is probably not supported by your XML processor.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:06.044+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646846044] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF_FACES-60142:ParserConfigurationException was thrown. The feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd' is probably not supported by your XML processor.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.403+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adf.share.security] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847403] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF Credential Store is not supported on this platform. Using the ADFNoCredentialSupportStore instead.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.403+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adf.share.security] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847403] [levelValue: 900] [[
  ADF Credential Store is not supported on this platform. Using the ADFNoCredentialSupportStore instead.]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.731+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847731] [levelValue: 800] [[
  loadImportedJpx - entering for jpx: model.Model]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loaded field type 'URI' -> 'oracle.adfinternal.model.businesseditor.fieldTypes.URI' from 'oracle.adf.businesseditor.model.Model.jpx']]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loaded field type 'Phone' -> 'oracle.adfinternal.model.businesseditor.fieldTypes.Phone' from 'oracle.adf.businesseditor.model.Model.jpx']]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loaded field type 'Email' -> 'oracle.adfinternal.model.businesseditor.fieldTypes.Email' from 'oracle.adf.businesseditor.model.Model.jpx']]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  loadImportedJpx - found jpx: oracle.adf.businesseditor.model.Model.jpx]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  loadImportedJpx - found jpx: oracle.adfinternal.model.businesseditor.adfmBusinessEditorModel.jpx]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.778+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847778] [levelValue: 800] [[
  loadImportedJpx - this jpx added: model.Model.jpx]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerJpxes - jpxList 0: oracle.adf.businesseditor.model.Model]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerJpxes - jpxList 1: oracle.adfinternal.model.businesseditor.adfmBusinessEditorModel]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerJpxes - jpxList 2: model.Model]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerJpxes - jpxList 3: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCat]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  getMergedJpx - mainJpxName: null, not found]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  getMergedJpx - merged jpx is merged CP jpx]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  getMergedJpx - merged cpx]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Jpx FullName: __JPX_Merged__]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Jpx mSubstitutes: 16]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Jpx mDiscrCatalog: 9]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Jpx mFieldTypes: 3]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOEntityDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.EntityObjectDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatOperationDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.OperationDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEditableViewDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.PublishedViewObjectDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatPDefViewObject->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.ViewObjectExtension]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatViewLinkDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.ViewLinkDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.794+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847794] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOAttributeDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.AttributeDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatPDefEntityObject->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.EntityObjectExtension]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatViewDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.ViewObjectDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOPDefEntityObject->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.EntityObjectExtension]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOViewLinkDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.ViewLinkDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEntityDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.EntityObjectDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEntityAssoc->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.EntityAssociation]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOPDefViewObject->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.ViewObjectExtension]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatAttributeDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.views.AttributeDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOViewDef->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.ViewObjectDefinition]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:07.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.Jpx] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646847810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  registerSubstitutes - old: oracle.jbo.syscat.SysCatEOEntityAssoc->oracle.adf.businesseditor.syscatext.entities.EntityAssociation]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:08.138+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.customizations.def] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646848138] [levelValue: 800] [[
  oracle.jbo.convert.pdefs not set]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:08.138+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.customizations.def] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646848138] [levelValue: 800] [[
  DefinitionManager.mConvertPDefs = 0]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:09.997+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [AssocDefLogger] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646849997] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Assoc accessor added, accessorName = Spares]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:10.169+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [AssocDefLogger] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646850169] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Assoc accessor added, accessorName = Maintenance]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:11.325+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646851325] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:13.138+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1637646853138] [levelValue: 800] [[
  hellllllo=APPSYSnullnullnullnull]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:13.153+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.ViewCriteria] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646853153] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Invalid operator used for VCItem Username in VC __DefaultViewCriteria__]]

[2021-11-23T07:54:13.169+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [oracle.adf.model.log.ViewCriteria] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1637646853169] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Invalid operator used for VCItem Password in VC __DefaultViewCriteria__]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed JSF  from version 2.2 to 2.1 and it works well